# PIC USART code not working

Tags: pic, microchip, mplab, usart

I have covered lately adc and lcd in microcontroller and gone into USART and as usual my first code I make is not working and I need some help with discovering the problem, here's the code:

Transmitter code:

main.c:

```
  #include "config.h"

  void main(){
  TRISCbits.TRISC6 = 1;
  TRISCbits.TRISC7 = 1;
  TRISDbits.TRISD0 = 1;

  SPBRG = 25;

  TXSTAbits.TX9 = 0;
  TXSTAbits.SYNC = 0;
  TXSTAbits.BRGH = 1;
  TXSTAbits.TXEN = 1;

  RCSTAbits.SPEN = 1;
  RCSTAbits.RX9 = 0;
  RCSTAbits.CREN = 0;

  while(1){
      while(TRMT == 0);
      if(PORTDbits.RD0 == 1){
             TXREG = 0xFF;
  }else{
          TXREG = 0;
  }

  }
  }
```

Receiver code:

main.c:

```
    #include "config.h"

    char recieve;

    void main(){
        TRISCbits.TRISC6 = 1;
        TRISCbits.TRISC7 = 1;
        TRISDbits.TRISD0 = 0;
        PORTDbits.RD0 = 0;

        SPBRG = 25;

        TXSTAbits.TX9 = 0;
        TXSTAbits.SYNC = 0;
        TXSTAbits.BRGH = 1;
        TXSTAbits.TXEN = 1;

        RCSTAbits.SPEN = 1;
        RCSTAbits.RX9 = 0;
        RCSTAbits.CREN = 0;

        while(1){

            RCREG = recieve;

            if(recieve == 0xFF){
                PORTDbits.RD0 = 1;
            }else{
                PORTDbits.RD0 = 0;
            }

        }
    }
```

and for both transmitter and receiver projects config.h is a header file where I set the frequency of crystal oscillator and configuration bits so it is the same file/code for both projects

config.h:

```
         /* 
         * File:   config.h
         * Author: Fady
         *
         * Created on August 25, 2014, 1:53 PM
         */


        // PIC16F877A Configuration Bit Settings

        // 'C' source line config statements

        #include <xc.h>

        // #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
        // Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

        // CONFIG
        #pragma config FOSC = XT        // Oscillator Selection bits (XT oscillator)
        #pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
        #pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
        #pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR enabled)
        #pragma config LVP = ON         // Low-Voltage (Single-Supply) In-Circuit Serial Programming Enable bit (RB3/PGM pin has PGM function; low-voltage programming enabled)
        #pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM code protection off)
        #pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits (Write protection off; all program memory may be written to by EECON control)
        #pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)

        #define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000
```

---

**EDIT**

---

I am trying to communicate 2 pic microcontrollers in which if I press the button on D0 in transmitter it sends a 0xFF data and then the receiver checks for if the received data == 0xFF if yes it turns on the LED on D0 in receiver but when I connect it on isis the TX pin of receiver keeps blinking high and low (red and blue) each half a second but when I press the button the high (red) signal keeps for a bit longer but keeps flashing with high and low and I suppose this is for start bit but the receiver doesn't turn on the led that's the error part I don't know what's wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Its just a very stupid silly c programming mistake I wrote:

RCREG = recieve;

which will take the value of receive and assign it to RCREG instead it should be

receive = RCREG;

which will assign the value of RCREG to receive and worked after building...